# Simple browser automation (IE) using Java

Tags: java, browser, automation

I am working on a project to provide a java program to end user. It will open a new browser (IE) then quickly visit a site (to get cookie). Then visit the second site at the same tab. So the flow is

1. Open IE
2. Visit first site and stay 2 seconds
3. Visit the second site at same tab (or open it on second tab but close first tab because user doesn't want to see it)

I tried Selenium and it works. However, end user has to install the web driver on their side, which may make it hard.

Is there other way can finish the simple task but doesn't require any extra file/installation at end user side?

Really appreciate any help!

Edited: I don't have to use Java. Any other way to achieve it in Windows is OK. Is powershell able to do that?

Comment: Well, what is your use case? I mean why does it have to be on the end user device if he has no interaction at all?

Comment: What happens after step 3?  If there is no additional user interaction with the browser, then use something like Apache's [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to visit the sites.  Here's an example to [access the cookie store](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java).

Comment: Hi DamCx, visiting the first site is to get some cookies and allow user to visit the second site. Ideally, user doesn't want to see the first site.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks. Will check it out. After step 3, user is on his own. He already log in now. (without second step, user doesn't have cookie and can't log in the second site)